# Replace fragment by menu

Tags: android, replace

I'd like to replace a fragment, when a menu button is clicked. The toast is displayed, but it seems like I have a problem with the FragmentTransaction, since it tells me it

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Cannot instantiate the type FragmentTransaction ActivityAppLaunch.java  /juraQuiz/src/com/pthuermer/juraquiz    line 71 Java Problem

this is what I tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.actionbar_menu_info) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        FragmentTransaction ft = new FragmentTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentInfo();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

    }
    if (id == R.id.actionbar_menu_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settigns", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try FragmentManager

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new FragmentInfo();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: `The method replace(int, android.app.Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)` is what it says